# alternative jdbc-river and shield

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river, elasticsearch-shield

My goal is that I have admin rights on kibana 4. I wish I could edit the content and save dashboard, etc... and to share its with others users.
But I don't want the others users should be able to save my dashboard or to remove its, etc... Only that they have rights in reading.

I tried and I successed to install plugin shield for to have the authentication on elasticsearch but on kibana 4 essentially. I configured correctly the roles of users and admin.
I arrived to save data through logstash, however, for mysql connection and through jdbc-river-plugin, I find an error with jdbc and authorization :

```
[2015-04-16 11:19:39,096][WARN ][river.routing            ] [node_test] failed to get/parse _meta for [mysql_mantis]
org.elasticsearch.shield.authz.AuthorizationException: action [indices:data/read/get] is unauthorized for user [__es_system_user]
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.authz.InternalAuthorizationService.denial(InternalAuthorizationService.java:247)
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.authz.InternalAuthorizationService.authorize(InternalAuthorizationService.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.action.ShieldActionFilter.apply(ShieldActionFilter.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:165)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:82)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.execute(NodeClient.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.get(AbstractClient.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetRequestBuilder.doExecute(GetRequestBuilder.java:201)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:73)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.routing.RiversRouter.updateRiverClusterState(RiversRouter.java:137)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.routing.RiversRouter$1.execute(RiversRouter.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.cluster.RiverClusterService$1.run(RiverClusterService.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I explain that before without shield-plugin installation, everything was working well.
I read that it's not compatible with shield-plugin and jdbc-river-plugin.

Exists it one alternative for to have a compatibility with authentication and mysql connection, so an alternative with shield-plugin or jdbc-river-plugin? 
And with shield-plugin, I risk to find an other error in 30 day because it's trial version.

Can I replace shield-plugin with LDAP-river-plugin or with elasticsearch-security-plugin or other?
And can I replace jdbc-river-plugin with mongodb-river-plugin or with couchdb-river-plugin or other?

Thanks!